# How can I dismiss unwanted pages of my two pages consisting interface controller after pushing a new interface over it? On Watchkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, segue, watchkit

I was trying to push an interface after clicking at one button of my two pages consisting rootController and got a weird result.

[image]

[image]

My requested controller (second image) gets pushed over my first page..but, the second page of my root controller is still there and I can segue into it.

I don't want this.

How can I dismiss all other pages of my several pages controller after pushing a new interface over it?.

Modal is not an option as I want to go deeper after pushing this controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WatchKit does not support pushing an interface controller in a page-based navigation layout. As of Xcode beta 4, I understand that you won't see this strange behaviour as the interface simply will not be presented.

Comment: yes, that's exactly the main problem here. But it would be great if Apple make it possible, it shouldn't be so difficult and the results (visually) would be stunning!