# Is Xcode 6.2 beta 4 making watchKit interfaces with pages unable to open pushed interfaces?

Tags: ios, xcode, swing, watchkit, apple-watch

Until XCode 6.2 beta 3 I was able to navigate in the hierarchy and push new interfaces from a button on any of my two pages relationated interfaces controllers.

Such as this:
[image]

This used to make such a weird result as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072896/how-can-i-dismiss-unwanted-pages-of-my-two-pages-consisting-interface-controller)

But now, this appears to be a no go. Xcode doesn't state anything on this matter to alert, it just do nothing when you tap on the button that push the new interface.

I can only change that push for a modal to get it work.

But that is limiting my navigation stack as modal are final nodes of the navigation tree.

Also, this is a no go too:

[image]

XCode is forcing me to obtain this result only if that push is changed for a modal!!!!

Any workaround please!

This is tying my hands at my back.

Comment: what is your question exactly ? what you want to do ?

Comment: Hi NSSakly, I want to navigate from a page based interface. Right now I'm reading some stuff from apple and it appears to be impossible. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you are describing, and it is by design. If you were able to do it in a previous Xcode beta, Apple presumably saw that as a bug. They have been quite explicit that you can choose either page-based or hierarchical-interfaces, and that these are mutually exclusive. Both have the ability to present a modal view at any time.

From the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH12-SW1):

> ### Interface Navigation
>
> For WatchKit apps with more than one screen of content, you must choose a technique for navigating between those screens. WatchKit apps support two navigation styles, which are mutually exclusive:
>
> - **Page-based.** This style is suited for apps with simple data models where the data on each page is not closely related to the data on any other page. A page-based interface contains two or more independent interface controllers, only one of which is displayed at any given time. At runtime, the user navigates between interface controllers by swiping left or right on the screen. A dot indicator control at the bottom of the screen indicates the user’s current position among the pages.
> - **Hierarchical.** This style is suited for apps with more complex data models or apps whose data is more hierarchical. A hierarchical interface always starts with a single root interface controller. In that interface controller, you provide controls that, when tapped, push new interface controllers onto the screen.
>     Apps can use modal presentations to supplement their base navigation style. Modal presentations are a way to interrupt the current user workflow to request input or display information. You can present interface controllers modally from both page-based and hierarchical apps. The modal presentation itself can consist of a single screen or multiple screens arranged in a page-based layout.